# Распространить функцию на новые элементы

Tags: javascript, jquery

К примеру, есть функция

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $( '.element' ).someFunc();
  
});
```

Работает все отлично, но если добавлять через JS новые элементы с классом .element - ее придется вызывать снова. Есть ли возможность поставить отслеживание появления элементов с классом .element и автоматически к ним применять данную функцию?

Comment: Сразу после создания и вставки элемента в DOM, нужно применить эту функцию. Т.е. нужно найти то место, где элемент рендерится в DOM.

Comment: нужно будет руками вызывать ее в момент создания элемента. По другому не получится

Comment: @ThisMan получится.

Answer (score 0):

```js
addButton = function() {
  $("body").append("<button class='buttons'>Hi</button>")
}

$(".buttons").on("click", addButton)

$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', function(event) {
  $(event.target).on("click", addButton)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="buttons">Hi</button>
```

Comment: Одним `ready` не обойтись. JQ не будет вечно следить за появлением новых элементов в DOM.

Comment: @MishaSaidov поправил свой ответ (вспомнил как этот обработчик называется).